# Neo4j - Create Nodes from nested JSON file and list

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am new to Neo4j and especially with Cypher query. I am trying to create nodes for the values in the JSON file as you can see its in a nested format. Using `MERGE` because I need the values like 'Adam Smith' as a single node from the nested list below. It clearly works well when 'organization' is not in nested/list format. Please see below of my try out and comments. Really appreciate the help!

Sample data.json

```
[   {   'organization': 'MIT',
        'student_names': ['Adam Smith'],
        'unique_id': 'ABC123'},
    {   'organization': 'Harvard',
        'student_names': ['Adam Smith', 'Cate Scott'],
        'unique_id': 'ABC124'},
    {   'organization': 'Harvard',
        'student_names': ['Mandy T.', 'Bob Smith'],
        'unique_id': 'ABC125'}]
```

Creates 2 nodes for organization - works

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///data.json') YIELD value as v 
MERGE (o:org {name: v.organization})
// Added 2 labels, created 2 nodes, set 2 properties, completed after 5 ms.
```

Doesn't work

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///data.json') YIELD value as v 
UNWIND v.student_names as s
MERGE(st:student {name: s.student_names})
```

Error: `Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Type mismatch: expected a map but was String("Adam Smith")`

Looking for a graph untangled like this. I think I can define the relation on my own, I am just looking to see how to create nodes to begin with.

```
ABC123 --> MIT --> Adam Smith 
ABC124 --> Harvard --> Adam Smith
ABC124 --> Harvard --> Cate Scott
ABC125 --> Harvard --> Mandy T.
ABC125 --> Harvard --> Bob Smith
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second query, `s` is already the name of a student, so just do this:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///data.json') YIELD value
UNWIND value.student_names AS s
MERGE(st:student {name: s})
```